# Cannot Edit the data saved in the database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using cake php for project, but i cannot edit the data i saved in the database. The edit function i used in the controller looks like below.

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Seller->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid seller'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->Seller->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The seller has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The seller could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Seller.' . $this->Seller->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Seller->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

My edit.ctp file looks like below.

```
<div class="sellers form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Seller'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Seller'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('phone_no');
        echo $this->Form->input('address');
        echo $this->Form->input('latitide');
        echo $this->Form->input('longitude');
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('product_type');
        echo $this->Form->input('product_description');
        echo $this->Form->input('approval');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $this->Form->value('Seller.id')), array(), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $this->Form->value('Seller.id'))); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Sellers'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can save and delete data in the database, but when i edit the saved data, saved changes are not getting saved. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get the flash message saying "The seller could not be saved. Please, try again.", or do you get nothing in return?

Comment: No. when I save data they are getting successfully saved. But when i edit the saved data they are getting edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this :

```
$this->Seller->primaryKey= $id;
```

just before the first if .

**edited - code working**

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->Category->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Category->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid category'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->Category->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Catégorie modifiée avec succès'),array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
            $this->flash(__('Categorie pas modifiée...Réessayer Plus tard'),array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->Category->read(null, $id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: here is my code and it's working ( look at the answer edited )

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are able to add/delete, and not edit is because the primary key is not being submitted with the form. $id will only be there on initial page load, not when the form is submitted, since it then relies on the id being in $this->request->data. A good way to check if this is the case is to look in the database table you are saving to. If there is a new inserted record with the data you are trying to save, then this is it.

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Seller->id = $id
    if (!$this->Seller->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid seller'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->Seller->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The seller has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The seller could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Seller->read(null, $id);
    }
}
```

@may was correct, only he was referring to a different Model name than what you were using: it should be `Seller` not `Category`.

I would also change your `find()` call to use `read()` instead:
`$this->request->data = $this->Seller->read(null, $id);`